# Phonegap with jquery mobile collapsable content issue in mobile devices

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile

I have created one quote app using phonegap with jquery mobile collpasable for android.when I run the same code in computer it just works fine and to the surprised few times it just work fine in mobile also but most of the times it will not show any data in mobile devices but in desktop it will always work.I tried everything but of no use.here is my desktop link.
Way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/collapse.php

Here is android apk.
http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/quote.apk

does not work on newer version of jquery,here is details

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/4/5/Collapsible-content-and-Ajax-loading-with-jQuery-Mobile#cC31B6DEC-D263-F1C2-6CA71EACBFF8ADE5

Any guide/suggestion will be very helpful

Comment: You should let us more information about the problem: tap events, ajax request... what's wrong exactly?

Comment: @oscarvady there is no issue in the code as it is working just fine in computer browser.you can see the above link given. the problem is mobile.android i think jquery mobile does not work properly.sometimes it loads but most of the times does not load in android

Comment: I checked out your source and you are using very old versions of jQM (1.0a4) and jQuery (1.5.2). I suggest you update these before proceeding.

Comment: @balzafin i tried with latest version of jquery but it is not working for my purpose as i am dynamically loading every content from server side.

Comment: Could you specify why you can't load dynamic content with newer versions of jQuery?

Comment: @balzafin in phonegap the main file is index.html not index.php so we cant include php files using include.In index.html file i am using jquery to load complete page  collapse.php. same thing is not working using new jquery version

Comment: @balzafin this links explains that it does not work on newer version of jquery  http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/4/5/Collapsible-content-and-Ajax-loading-with-jQuery-Mobile#cC31B6DEC-D263-F1C2-6CA71EACBFF8ADE5

Comment: No it doesn't. There's just two people saying in the comment section that _they_ didn't get it to work. Try to update to **jquery 1.11.1** and **jQM 1.4.5** and use `on` instead of `live`.

Comment: @balzafin i think only two people have tried that approach.If you can give one try with latest jquery and make it work i will be very thankful.I have tried but failed

Comment: Try to also use `collapsibleexpand` instead of `expand` on your event listener. That's the event in the jQM documentation: http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-collapse. If it's still not working, update your page with these changes and I can debug it from the link you provided.

Comment: Please post what have you tried and failed so we can pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @balzafin changed to collapsibleexpand.its not working in mobile devices

Comment: You haven't updated your jQuery and jQM versions. If you don't do that I'm not able to help. You must also wrap your code to document ready: `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });`

Comment: @balzafin which jqm version u advice

Comment: I already did 4 hours ago: jquery 1.11.1 and jQM 1.4.5. http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Comment: @balzafin updated the latest version.but now its not even fetching data in computer here is the link of new version http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/collapse97.php

Comment: You can't manipulate the page with jQuery before the DOM is ready. So like I said already, you must wrap your code like this: `$( document ).ready(function() {
    // code here
});`. Read this carefully: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @balzafin wow it worked in pc.let me check in mobile.

Comment: @balzafin same problem.few times it loads the content in mobile and most of the times it does not load anything

Comment: @balzafin same problem.in mobile not at all loading however i am giving absolute link for mobile devices and relative link for pc.i tried more than 10 times it never fetched data in mobile but fetched in pc

Comment: [Debug](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) the app and see if it throws any errors in the console. You can also catch errors in your `load()`. Instructions here: http://api.jquery.com/load/- Search for: _Display a notice if the Ajax request encounters an error._

Comment: @balzafin this is link of android app.same this working fine from browsers in android but app is not working http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/1/outfile1.apk

Comment: @balzafin thx for awesome idea to connect android app with pc and debug .trying that

Comment: Yes it's an awesome tool. It may save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: @balzafin i tried everything but there is no error .dont know why phonegap is not fetching data .if u can give ur few min,i will be thankful  .here is my android app http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/1/outfile1.apk

Comment: @balzafin i think its phonegap issue